# Generic classes in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have three Classes:

1. Generic Class  that has 3 fields - a boolean, a String for a message, and a T result.
2. A second class that is having the function to multiply two numbers passed as method parameters. The return type of this method is the generic class #1.
3. The third Class is the same as the second, but instead, I am concatenating two string parameters.

Question: How can my Generic class be used to display the result, the message, and the boolean for example, from Class #2?

Baiscally, Class.result should display the multiplied numbers.

```
public class ClassOne<T> {

    boolean success;
    String errorMessage;
    T result;
}

public class ClassTwo {

public ClassOne<Long> multiplyNumbers(Long num1, Long num2) {
}

}
```

Comment: Assuming success: `return new ClassOne<>(true, "no error", num1 * num2);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to instantiate it with the generic type

```java
public ClassOne<Long> multiplyNumbers(Long num1, Long num2) {
    ClassOne<Long> c = new ClassOne<>();
    try {
        Long multiplied = num1 * num2;
        c.setResult(multiplied);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        c.setError(e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
}
```

For `String` concatenation, it would be the same, except I don't see how an exception could be thrown

```java
public ClassOne<String> concatStrings(String string1, String string2) {
    ClassOne<Long> c = new ClassOne<>();
    c.setResult(string1 + string2);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I did try this as my first thought, but when I instantiate the ClassOne on the main method, the getter for result will be null/is ignored. So, in this case how can I create an instance of the ClassOne in the Main to check that stored information? I'm sorry if my question is unclear, I am trying to figure out how this information is stored and how I can verify it in the Main method.

Comment: @aLostProgrammer I'm afraid I don't understand the problematic, maybe an edit of the question  will do?

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your reply as the answer as it did guide me in the right direction.